# adding a back button to the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am designing a website such that a question appears on each page and users can go through the questions by clicking on the "Next" button at the bottom of every page and proceed to the next page. I want to add a back button as well so that they can go the previous pages and change their answers whenever needed.
This is the HTML code for the "Next" button:

```
<button ng-disabled="question.answer === undefined || question.answer == '' || question.answer == {}" ng-click="RC.nextQuestion()" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right ; margin-top:20px">Next</button>
```

This is the JavaScript code for the "Next" button:

```
this.next = function(){
        if(self.state == "workerIdSlide"){
            if(self.questionId == null && self.partId == null){
                self.load(function(){
                    self.state = self.allStates[++self.slideIndex];
                });
                return;
            }
        }
        if(self.slideIndex + 1 < self.allStates.length){
            self.state = self.allStates[++self.slideIndex];
        }else{
            self.submitResults(self.resultsSubmitted, self.handleError);
        }
    };
```

This is what I tried as for the JavaScript code:

```
this.previous = function(){
        if(self.state == "workerIdSlide"){
            if(self.questionId == null && self.partId == null){
                self.load(function(){
                    self.state = self.allStates[--self.slideIndex];
                });
                return;
            }
        }
    };
    this.previousQuestion = function(){
        if(self.questionIndex == 0{
            ++self.questionIndex;
        else{
            self.previous();
        }
    };
```

But, it did not work. Can someone tell me how I can add a "Back" button?

Comment: is your next button working?

Comment: Yes. The next button works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
this.previousQuestion = function(){
            if(self.questionIndex != 0){
                --self.questionIndex;
            }else{
              if(self.questionIndex + 1 >= self.questions.length){
                self.next();
              }
            }
        };
```

Remove:

```
this.previous = function(){
        if(self.state == "workerIdSlide"){
            if(self.questionId == null && self.partId == null){
                self.load(function(){
                    self.state = self.allStates[--self.slideIndex];
                });
                return;
            }
        }
    };
```

The complete code:

```
this.next = function(){
            if(self.state == "workerIdSlide"){
                if(self.questionId == null && self.partId == null){
                    self.load(function(){
                        self.state = self.allStates[++self.slideIndex];
                    });
                    return;
                }
            }

            if(self.slideIndex + 1 < self.allStates.length){
                self.state = self.allStates[++self.slideIndex];
            }else{
                self.submitResults(self.resultsSubmitted, self.handleError);
            }
        };

        this.nextQuestion = function(){
            if(self.questionIndex + 1 < self.questions.length){
                ++self.questionIndex;
            }else{
                self.next();
            }
        };
        this.previousQuestion = function(){
            if(self.questionIndex != 0){
                --self.questionIndex;
            }else{
              if(self.questionIndex + 1 >= self.questions.length){
                self.next();
              }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).